# Upcoming medical examination and interview the same day; how to handle PTO with current boss?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, employer-relations, time-off

So I’ve got an interview Friday with a job that seems like the perfect fit. My current work situation has become increasingly toxic and has forced me to seek new opportunities. That being said, I am still very fearful of burning bridges with this company’s management.

I have already been approved to go to a medical examination on Friday, however, by telling him the kind of procedure I thought of, he looked it up and saw that it would only take an hour. Nevertheless, my interview is in another city and I would need the entire second half of the day off.

To further complicate things, my boss was out for part of the day because HIS boss just had a death in the family last night.

I have a note from my therapist that I could use to take “personal time” whenever I need since I suffer anxiety and depression, however, I still don’t know if my employer would buy it since he’s already suspicious after my medical study.

Is there any potential drawback in taking the whole day off? I’m considering just playing hooky Friday afternoon but I feel that could end miserably..

Comment: you should change your user name, no?

Comment: *by telling him the kind of procedure I **thought of**..* By "thought of" are you saying you made something up and there isn't an actual medical appointment? Or is the appointment for something else and you just didn't want to disclose the actual issue to your boss?

Answer (score 1):

I can see why you want to leave.

"Boss, I talked to the doctor and he said that sometimes there are complications and I might need to have them addressed, as well.” “What complications, Dan?” “It has something to do with my kidneys but I don’t remember exactly. Look, I don’t really feel comfortable discussing details of my medical history with you.” (I suggest you have a very repulsive and long winded backup story ready, something like "If you really want to know, I have a cyst in an unpleasant place.  They want to drain it because where it is, they think it might get infected and cause something called 'septicaemia.' The doctor said it was probably nothing but...")

I am not sure if they can press you for details of your medical conditions, real and fictitious, if you don’t want to give details.

I think you need to take some time on Friday to recover from the "anxiety and depression" of the medical procedure.  ("I hate needles and they had to draw a lot of blood.")

Good luck getting away from that boss.

Comment: I would not suggest a direct lie.  Getting caught would be unpleasant.

Answer (score 1):

> I still don’t know if my employer would buy it since he’s already suspicious after my medical study.

You indicate **you have already been approved for your medical appointment**, so I say you already have permission to leave for that day (unless your boss specifically said you had to return).

If you are not sure you got the whole day *ask your boss* for confirmation, moment in which you could try negotiate if he expects you to return.

You say you have a **note from your therapist/physician**, which is a **strong and valid justification** for you to ask for the rest of the day off (the procedure itself may be quick but it surely involves at least some recovery).

I must say it was not necessary to go into much details on the specifics of the examinations, as those things are *private* to you (feel free to not disclose the details next time, in a polite fashion of course).